# get AT command call response

Tags: command, at-command

I'm trying a code to make a voice call using usb modem and it succeeded to make a call... now i want to get that call response to know if number is ringing,busy or unavailable

This is my used code:

```
      string number = textBox1.Text;

        po.PortName = "COM3";
        po.BaudRate = int.Parse("9600");
        po.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32("8");
        po.Parity = Parity.None;
        po.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        po.ReadTimeout = int.Parse("300");
        po.WriteTimeout = int.Parse("300");
        po.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        po.Open();
        po.DtrEnable = true;
        po.RtsEnable = true;
        po.Write("ATDT "+number+";\r"); 

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);

        po.WriteLine("ATH+CHUP;\r");
        po.DiscardInBuffer();
        po.DiscardOutBuffer();
        po.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

After ATD, you need reading the port for kind of information called URC.

For voice call, there are the following possible response,

> If no dialtone 
>   NO DIALTONE
>   If busy,
>   BUSY 
>   If connection cannot be set up:
>   NO CARRIER 
>   NO ANSWER

And, before ATD, you'd better set the error format using **at+cmee**, for exam, at+cmee=2 will enable the string format.

EDIT：(Here is an example with python)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import serial


NUM = "111111111"

ser = serial.Serial("com1", 115200)

ser.write('at+cmee=2\r')
ser.timeout = 10.0
res = "invalid"
while len(res) > 0:
    res = ser.read(1)
    print(res, end='')

ser.write('atd' + NUM + ';\r')
ser.timeout = 60.0
res = "invalid"
while len(res) > 0:
    res = ser.read(1)
    print(res, end='')

ser.write("AT+CHUP\r")
ser.timeout = 10.0
res = "invalid"
while len(res) > 0:
    res = ser.read(1)
    print(res, end='')
```

Its output is (I reject the call from the phone "111111111"),

```
at+cmee=2
OK
atd111111111;
OK

NO CARRIER
AT+CHUP
+CME ERROR: operation not allowed
```

And, after the output of 'no carrier', there is no more need to hang up.

Comment: could you give me full example with syntax